# Creating a Timeline and SQL Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Language: C#
Compiler: Visual Studio 2012
O/S: Windows 7 Home Premium

Here is a question thats been on many questions, and through a few debates.
I know there are currently provisional .net controls for a functional timeline, as well as hints and tips on how a process would be done, but I have not found (so far) a complete tutorial on a well-maintained SQL-Storage Timeline system.

I need to document almost every change that my site will have. From the addition to user reputation, to the joining / creating and eventual submissions of members, clans games etc.
As far as I know, **DateTime** in a SQL database should be avoided, especially in large quantities.

What would be the implementation, process, and eventual output of a Timeline?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `DateTime` - you just need to know how to use it properly (such as always storing values in UTC, and noting that .NET and MSSQL have different Minimum Values (0001-01-01 vs 1753-01-01 respectively).

Comment: Would 1 table to store all this data (note that there **possible** is a big growth potential on the site) be able to manage, while being queried a lot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is sometimes known as "Audit history" - and it's often implemented using a single, denormalized, table, however many DB purists will argue against it as you lose strong typing.

The table looks like this:

```
AuditTable( EventId bigint, DateTime datetime, Subject nvarchar, Table varchar, Column varchar, TablePK bigint, OldValueInt bigint nullable, OldValueStr nvarchar nullable )
-- add more nullable columns for more types, if necessary
```

Each time a value is changed, such as a user's reputation being increased, you would add a row to this table, such as this:

```
INSERT INTO AuditTable( Now(), N'User reputation increased', 'Users', 'Reputation', @userId, 100 )
```

You only need to store the old value (the value before the change) because the new (i.e. current) value will be in the actual table row.

Adding to the Audit table can be done entirely automatically with SQL Server table triggers.

To view a user's reputation history, you would do this:

```
SELECT * FROM AuditTable WHERE Table = 'Users' AND Column = 'Reputation' AND TablePK = @userId
```

Now as I said, this design is more for auditing rather than maintaining an easily user-accessible history, these are the disadvantages:

- You cannot semantically index the table, so lookups and lists will always be slow
- You're storing database metadata as strings, so there's a lot of overhead
- There's no referential integrity (this can be a good thing in that the data will remain if you re-architecture the original tables, e.g. removing the Reputation field from the Users table)

If you want to be more "pure" then you really have to design a table structure that directly supports the history-tracking you want to build. You don't need to create a history table for every field - even Stackoverflow doesn't store a history of everything. For example:

```
 UserReputationHistory ( UserId bigint, ReputationChange int, DateTime when, Subject nvarchar )
```

Of course it does complicate your code to have to maintain these disparate FooHistory tables.

The other things in in your original question that you comment, such as a member's join date doesn't need a history table, you can get that from a `DateJoined` field in the member's own DB row.

Comment: Wow, this has been amazingly insightful, I really appreciate such an in-depth response.
When you said 'many DB purists will argue against it', do you know what they would be arguing towards? As I get the impression that Auditing is just one solution.

Comment: You must be new to the Internet - people don't argue in favour of a better alternative, they'll just belittle whatever solution you come up with. In this case, they'd cite the disadvantages I mentiond - the only real alternative is to labouriously create `FooHistory` tables for each entity attribute value you want to track over time.

Comment: Agreed. Was just trying to look for a silver lining :D Thanks for the insight to this conundrum.